# Why window properties like `scrollY` don't update automatically after assignment?

Tags: javascript

So I was playing around with javascript window properties and I tried overriding the `window.scrollY` property and I noticed that after I run `window.scrollY = 123` it stays at the `123` value even after scrolling and it doesn't update with the scroll position.

I am aware of the fact that there are special methods like `window.scrollTo` for setting the scroll position but I just find this wired.

Comment: Why? Because it's not designed to be used that way. Nothing more than that

Comment: [`scrollY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY) is a **read-only** property.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts supposed to me anyway....seems you can set it at least in some browsers when you really shouldn't be able to

Answer (score 0):

You can reproduce such behavior in an object where if a property isn't explicitly set it returns some calculated value. But when it is set it returns the set value.

So while what you see seems strange it's really only because it was never intended for users to set `window.scrollY` and once you set it the value won't change when trying to retrieve it

```js
window.scrollTo(0,300)// set scrollY to 300 with proper setter

const fakeWindow = new Proxy({}, {
  get: function(target, name) {
    if (!(name in target) && name === 'scrollY') {
        console.log('Returning callculated')
        return window.scrollY;
    
    }
    console.log('Returning user set value')
    return target[name];
  }
});

console.log("[before set]" + fakeWindow.scrollY);
fakeWindow.scrollY = 5500;
console.log("[after set] " + fakeWindow.scrollY);
console.log('Actual window.scrollY=', window.scrollY)
```

```html
<div style="height:2000px"></div>
```

Comment: You don't need a `Proxy` to produce this behavior: `const fakeWindow = Object.create(window, {
  scrollY: {
    get () { ... }
  }
})`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts different strokes for different folks. Only trying to represent the behavior, how you arrive at doing it is irrelevant